# How to get Cookies in Server Component in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Error, when i get accessToken from cookies in nextjs 14.0.3

Error message - You're importing a component that needs next/headers. That only works in a Server Component but one of its parents is marked with "use client", so it's a Client Component.

```
import { HttpStatusCode } from 'axios'
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'

import { BASE_API_URL } from './axios'

interface FetchOptions extends RequestInit {
    queryParams?: Record<string, string>
}

function queryStringify(params: Record<string, string>): string {
    const query = new URLSearchParams(params)
    return query.toString()
}

export async function fetcher(url: string, options?: FetchOptions, authorizedRequest?: boolean): Promise<any> {
    try {
        const queryParams = options?.queryParams ? `?${queryStringify(options.queryParams)}` : ''
        let headers: HeadersInit = {
            ...options?.headers,
        }

        if (authorizedRequest) {
            const accessToken = cookies().get('accessToken')?.value

            if (accessToken) {
                headers = {
                    ...headers,
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
                }
            } else {
                throw new Error('Access token is not available for an authorized request')
            }
        }

        if (options?.method === 'POST' || options?.method === 'PUT') {
            headers = {
                ...headers,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
        }

        const response = await fetch(`${BASE_API_URL}${url}${queryParams}`, {
            ...options,
            headers,
        })

        if (!response.ok) {
            const status = response.status

            const errorStatusMap: Record<number, string> = {
                [HttpStatusCode.NotFound]: 'Not found',
                [HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized]: 'Unauthorized',
                [HttpStatusCode.Forbidden]: 'Forbidden',
                [HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError]: 'Internal server error',
                [HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed]: 'Method not allowed',
            }

            const errorMessage = errorStatusMap[status] || response.statusText

            throw { status, message: errorMessage }
        }

        return await response.json()
    } catch (error) {
        throw error
    }
}
```

I tried adding text 'use client'. Then when I send a request from the /api folder, I get an error

Comment: Where are you calling this fetcher?